# Compile OpenCV without GPU?

Tags: opencv, cmake, gpu

I've just run `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..` from `OpenCV/build`, and got in my output:

```
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video
                                    objdetect contrib nonfree gpu legacy photo python
                                    stitching ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    -
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera java world
```

The thing is, compilation with `gpu` fails, maybe because my machine doesn't have one? (It's an EC2 instance).

`make` fails with an odd error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_gpu
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/test_gpumat.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/utility.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/test_filters.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/test_copy_make_border.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/main.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/test_threshold.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/test_video.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/test_core.cpp.o
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/test_core.cpp.o] Error 4
make[1]: *** [modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've tried using the flag `-DOPENCV_MODULES_DISABLED_USER="gpu"` but that produces weird output with `gpu` listed as `to be built` *and* `disabled`.

```
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video objdetect contrib nonfree gpu legacy photo python stitching ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    gpu
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera java world
```

How do I compile without `gpu`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this particular problem in a most horrible way:

```
touch modules/gpu/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_gpu.dir/test/test_core.cpp.o
make
```

Compilation then completes ok. This isn't really a solution though, so I'd like to know if there's a proper fix.

Answer (score 22):

To disable building a specific module, use

```
-D BUILD_opencv_{modulename}=OFF
```

In this case, use

```
-D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF
```

Comment: From the latest [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) (3.4), this option does not seem to be used anymore. The `WITH_CUDA` option mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161826/2745495) seems to be way to go now.

Answer (score 15):

Try to add `-D WITH_CUDA=OFF` to your `cmake` command line.

Comment: +1 But it's interesting that it is trying to compile with GPU support.

Comment: This does not seem to work, on a clean build, adding `WITH_CUDA=OFF` to the `cmake` command still results in `gpu` still being listed as `to be built`.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with opencv-2.4.9 :)

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with opencv 3.4.0.

Answer (score 7):

For OpenCV 2.4.11 on EC2, I had to include both `-D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF` and `-D WITH_CUDA=OFF`. I also included `-D WITH_1394=OFF` to avoid a warning in python. So:

```
cd opencv-2.4.11/
mkdir release
cd release/
cmake -D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D WITH_1394=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: 1394 is error due to libdc1394, which is used to control and capture streams from IEEE 1394 based cameras. Nothing to do with python, if you are using Opencv on laptop, instead of server, this error would most likely go away.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by not having enough memory with your EC2 instance. I got a similar error (different module) with an EC2/Micro running Ubuntu 12.10, but it was smooth sailing on an EC2/Small.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is , your device run out off memory.
This happens when gcc don't have enough memory. Trust me, since I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. It's a memory issue; increasing the swap space fixed it for me. Open a terminal and enter this:

```
free
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.img bs=1024k count=1000
mkswap /var/swap.img
swapon /var/swap.img
free
```

Then proceed with your `make`.

[Source](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=304389.msg7374545#msg7374545)